# Prove the "Chebyshev's theorem"

Tags: prime-numbers, chebyshev-function

I know the Chebyshev's theorem for primes that is :
There is a $p$ between $n, 2n$ if $n>1$
Can you prove it easily?
Actually I'm just 13 years old and I couldn't find an answer that I can understand.
Thanks

Comment: There aren't any known easy proofs - it is surprisingly hard to prove. The most "basic" proofs still require a bit of math that most 13-year-olds haven't seen yet.

Comment: Could you please write that basic answer?

Comment: No, because it is very long and it can be found elsewhere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate

Comment: It is only "basic" in that it doesn't use calculus.

Comment: I advise you to grab a copy of "Proofs from THE BOOK". The proof is carried out there in a relatively easy way, and every result used is proved.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly confident in saying that the answer is no, no there is not an easy proof of this. Incase, you are still interested, the only thing that I could find (for those of us who don't speak German) is [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bertrand-Chebyshev_Theorem#Proof). This probably won't help you, and the lemmas aren't explained (not much is explained at all really), but it might give you a general sense for what the proof looks like. The original (in German) is cited at the bottom of the page, and I haven't personally gone through this proof to see if any mistakes are made.